# EXCEL VBA: how to increase the speed of this code

Tags: vba, excel

This code works. Since it has too many loop, loop inside loop, this works very slowly. How can we increase the speed of this program? 
I am trying to copy a range from one file to another file of same name in different folder. I have folders named "A","B","C"..."G" inside "c:\Charts\1\" & "c:\Charts\0\". Inside each folders "A","B","C"..."G" there are files named 1,2,3,4,..10.

My code is like this

```
vArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
Dim fileName1, Pathname1 As String
Pathname1 = "c:\Charts\1\"
Pathname="c:\charts\0\"
For Each vFile1 In vArr1
    fileName1 = Dir(Pathname1 & vFile1 & "\" & "*.xlsx")
    Do While fileName1 <> ""
        For Each vFile In vArr
            filename = Dir(Pathname & vFile & "\" & "*.xlsx")
            Do While filename <> ""
                If filename = fileName1 Then
                Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname1 & vFile & "\" & fileName1)
                    WB1.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    WB1.ActiveSheet.Range("M1:M30").Copy
                    WB1.Close (False)
                Set WBD1 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & vFile & "\" & filename)
                WBD1.ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
                    WBD1.ActiveSheet.Paste
                    WBD1.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "HSI Q4 2014-15"
                    WBD1.Close (True)
                    filename = Dir()
                Else

                End If
                fileName1 = filename
            Loop
        Next
    Loop
Next
```

How can we make this work faster?

Comment: `This code works` makes it inappropriate for SO. It would, however, be a **great** fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I'd recommend posting it there for some great help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is functional code that he is looking to optimize. It belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Okei.. I don't know about Code review.. I will post it there and delete it from here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am amazed that this code "does what it needs to do". I see the following bugs.

Bug1: There can be only one `Dir()` open at the same time. You use two nested `Dir()`s.

Bug2: look at the loop:

```
Do While filename <> ""
    If filename = fileName1
    ...
    End if
    fileName1 = filename
Loop
```

If at the first iteration `filename` isn't equal to `filename1` then it will be at the second iteration, however, it is not assured that the file exists in `pathname1` as it has not been obtained by a call to the topmost `Dir()` (which you can't because the second `Dir()` replaced the first one).

Maybe you should first specify what this code is supposed to do.